# How do I build Alpine Linux on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: embedded, alpine-linux, beagleboneblack

Currently, I am exploring Embedded Linux and found out that Alpine is a good place to start with that. Thus, I tried to build Alpine on BeagleBone. I tried out multiple methods:

1. The Generic ARM setup
2. This neat repository https://github.com/BrianSidebotham/alpine-on-bbb

I even tried to change the board up and try building it on STM32MP157D-DK1.
I am really not sure where I am going with it.
None of the lights on the board light up (SD Card Bootup) on either of devices.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "build Alpine linux" do you mean install. Could you [edit] to say what you tried so far. BBBs have a quirky boot sequence which is very common for ARM SBCs, they are all a bit different to each other.

Comment: If you are using a BBB, then Alpine is probably not a great choice, as it's not a common distro for the BBB. You're probably far better off starting with building debian images FOR the BBB (those are not built ON the BBB, but usually on a 'regular' computer). There are a lot of instructions and explanations for Debian on the BBB. Other options would be OpenEmbedded with Yocto or Buildroot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.